# Python docx library text align

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I am using python docx library to manipulate a word document. However I can't find how to align a line to the center in the documents page of that library. I can't find by google either.

```
    from docx import Document
    document = Document()
    p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
    p.add_run('bold').bold = True
    p.add_run(' and some ')
    p.add_run('italic.').italic = True
```

How can I align the text in docx?

Comment: I still couldn't find a solution to align text in python-docx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the new version of python-docx 0.7 https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/commit/158f2121bcd2c58b258dec1b83f8fef15316de19
 Add feature #51: Paragraph.alignment (read/write)
Now it is possible to align a paragraph as here: http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/par-alignment.html

```
 paragraph = document.add_paragraph("This is a text")
 paragraph.alignment = 0 # for left, 1 for center, 2 right, 3 justify ....
```

*edit from comments*

actually it is 0 for left, 1 for center, 2 for right

*edit 2 from comments*

You shouldn't hard code magic numbers like this. Use `WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER` to get the correct value for centering, etc. To do this use the following import

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
```

Comment: actually it is 0 for left, 1 for center, 2 for right

Comment: You shouldn't hard code magic numbers like this. Use `WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER` to get the correct value for centering, etc. To do this use the following import: `from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH`

Comment: Is there a way to add the alignment to a specific `run` part of the paragraph rather than the paragraph as a whole?

Answer (score 4):

```
p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ',style='BodyText', breakbefore=False, jc='left')# @param string jc: Paragraph alignment, possible values:left, center, right, both (justified), ...
```

for reference see this [reference](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/master/docx.py) at def paragraph read the documentation

Comment: Thank you but "add_paragraph() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jc'" .

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to align the heading section to center of the document, you have to get the document reference in a variable, like:

```
d1 = document.add_heading('PCM_Requirement Document', 0)
d1.alignment = 1
```

Paragraph reference will only work for the paragraph section not the heading section.