# Aligning Text/Formating Text - Docx - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-docx

I'm looking for a way to format a report that is being generated with Python. I've already reviewed [Python docx library text align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031011/python-docx-library-text-align), but this didn't work and didn't really meet my needs.

What I'm hoping to do is to format one paragraph center, another left, etc.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.section import WD_SECTION
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

document = Document()
app_name = "Company App Here"
consultant = "Jerry"

document.add_heading (app_name + "  Report",0)

document.add_paragraph("Testing performed by " + consultant) #How do I align this to the center?

document.add_page_break()

document.add_heading('Executive Summary\n',1)
document.add_paragraph('''\tThe blah blah blah text here''') #Align left and bold this paragraph

document.add_page_break()


document.save('./report.docx')
```

Answer (score 2):

This code Will Run For You

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.section import WD_SECTION
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

document = Document()
app_name = "Company App Here"
consultant = "Jerry"

document.add_heading (app_name + "  Report",0)

p1=document.add_paragraph("Testing performed by " + consultant)
p1.alignment=WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
document.add_page_break()

document.add_heading('Executive Summary\n',1)
p2=document.add_paragraph()
p2.add_run('\tThe blah blah blah text here').bold=True
p2.alignment=WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
document.add_page_break()


document.save('./report.docx')
```

This will generate a docx (as per the question's requirement).

Comment: it will generate a docx as per the questions requirement -.-