# Not able to set "right to left" alignment style for text in python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I am trying to write some text to a docx file using python-docx. I want to align the text from right to left and I have added a style for that, which is not working.

Here's the code:

```
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE

missingwords= Document()
styles = missingwords.styles
style = missingwords.styles.add_style('rtl', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
style.font.rtl = True

paragraph =missingwords.add_paragraph("Hello world",style='rtl')
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031011/python-docx-library-text-align)?

Comment: Yes, its working with that solution. But i have to add "paragraph.alignment = 0 " after adding every single paragraph. So i was trying to find a better solution to reduce line of codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't gotten around to playing with docx  yet (I've mostly used Excel python modules), but [based on the documentation here](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html?highlight=add_style#define-paragraph-formatting) it's looking like you're modifying the wrong property of style. The Font property, [per this definition of the rtl property](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Font.rtl), would only modify an [added run](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.add_run) (via `myparagraph.add_run("Hello World", style = "rtl")`).As far as I can tell, the code you're looking for is:

```
missingwords = Document()
style = missingwords.styles.add_style('rtl', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
style.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT
```

And then you can go ahead and add the paragraph like you were

```
paragraph = missingwords.add_paragraph("Hello world",style='rtl')
```

Again, just going off the documentation, so let me know if that works.