# Is there a way I can alight my text when writing to a word (.doc or .docx) file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, ms-word, file-handling

I've been trying to align my text in a word document using python but just can't seem to fight out how. this is my code:
`

```
import os 

my_text="Awesome words"
my_doc = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'file.docx')
open(my_doc,'wb').write(my_text.encode('utf8'))
```

`
Here's the output I'm getting

[image]

But here's what I want it to look like

[image]

tried

`

```
import os

my_text="Awesome words"
my_doc = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'file.docx')
open(my_doc,'wb').write(my_text.encode('utf8'))
```

`

expected

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: check out this library/module for handling '''docx''' files editing https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I cannot see any part of your code which involves any type of alignment.  However, this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031011/python-docx-library-text-align